# Problem with the drawable file missing ic_launcher

Tags: android, drawable

I opened my project and i deleted the `@drawable/ic_launcer_background` is there any way of reproducing that file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

Error Showing : `error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_background (aka com.example.project:drawable/ic_launcher_background) not found.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to File > New > Image Asset and It will show you below dialog.

[image]

In Icon type select **Launcher Icons (Adaptive and Legacy)** option.

In Asset Type select **Image** and from below path choose your image, Similarly you can select background layer.

Now Select Next and Finish, and your Icon will be changed. You can select Icon for foreground and background separately.

Comment: Not able to solve error after Above steps. Try to delete the folder  `/home/espl/Android-Studio-Projects/app/app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26' and rebuild the app It worked fine.                                                                                  Error: `AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_background (aka com.app:drawable/ic_launcher_background) not found.","sources":[{"file":"**/home/espl/Android-Studio-Projects/app/app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml**","position"{"startLine":2}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}`

Answer (score 1):

Go to File > New > Image Asset > select Background Layer

or, Go to res > right click on Drawable > New > Image Asset > select Background Layer

Answer (score 0):

**Please Open Image Asset By right click drawable folder and regenerate these vector images from there**
[image: Image Asset]